# How should we handle edits to answers to make code congruent with the language of the question?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

This is related to [What are our answer editing guidelines?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6097/120114), but about [an edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/116778) with a brief comment:

> Switched to python.

To me that makes sense, since the code looked like a mix of python and a c-based language. Others felt that edit shouldn't have been approved.

[Rolfl's answer to the aforementioned question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6099/120114) suggests:

> The solution is that code suggested edits, if they have an edit comment that makes logical/obvious sense, should just be approved. If there's a problem, well, the answerer whose code was edited will get a notification of the edit, and they can easily roll it back if it's wrong.

It seems that the consensus is that [answers should typically contain code in the same language as the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2630/120114).

Should we just [reject the suggested edit, and optionally downvote and/or comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50408725#50408725) instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Know what you are doing

If you know the language in question just like you know your best friend, then I'd say feel free to edit and correct it.

In this particular case the code was a mix of Python and some C-style language, so the edit makes perfect sense and I would have also voted to approve.

Think about what the best value for the site is. Don't just follow "rules" without thinking about *why* (i.e. don't decline the edit just because there might be a rule that says you should - think about why).

As rolfl said:

> The solution is that code suggested edits, if they have an edit comment that makes logical/obvious sense, should just be approved.

I think this edit is one that makes obvious sense.